# Calculating disk usage with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE versus file system?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-internals, database-size

MySQL's database size can be [calculated with](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-utilities/blob/08276b2258bf9739f53406b354b21195ff69a261/mysql/utilities/command/diskusage.py#L44)

```
SELECT table_schema AS db_name, SUM(data_length + index_length) AS size
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
GROUP BY db_name
```

But you can also calculate the database size by [looking at the disk-usage of the data-directory.](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-utilities/blob/08276b2258bf9739f53406b354b21195ff69a261/mysql/utilities/command/diskusage.py#L150) Should these two numbers ever deviate? Is there ever a reason to use one of these methods of the other? By extension, how is `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`'s `data_length` and `index_length` calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems like there are two ways the deviate in performance,

- **Statistics** when you query with `innodb_stats_on_metadata` (the default) you force the statistics to be updated (if it's not cached). You can turn this off, but doing so requires you make a `GLOBAL` change. [From the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html):

  > When `innodb_stats_on_metadata` is enabled, InnoDB updates non-persistent [statistics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_statistics) when metadata statements such as `SHOW TABLE STATUS` or **when accessing the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`** or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS` tables. (These updates are similar to what happens for `ANALYZE TABLE`.) When disabled, InnoDB does not update statistics during these operations. Leaving the setting disabled can improve access speed for schemas that have a large number of tables or indexes. It can also improve the stability of execution plans for queries that involve InnoDB tables.
  >
  > To change the setting, issue the statement `SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata=mode`, where mode is either `ON` or `OFF` (or `1` or `0`). Changing the setting requires privileges sufficient to set global system variables (see Section 5.1.9.1, “System Variable Privileges”) and immediately affects the operation of all connections.
- **Cache** else it seems that the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is reading from a cache in [`Table_statistics::get_stat`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8e797a5d6eb3a87f16498edcb7261a75897babae/sql/dd/info_schema/table_stats.cc#L357). That seems to be documented under [`information_schema_stats_expiry`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry). But it also seems you can refresh the cache with `ANALYZE` table (which the docs mention), and [the testing suite](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8e797a5d6eb3a87f16498edcb7261a75897babae/mysql-test/suite/ndb/t/ndb_dd_basic.test#L204). So the cache can drift by that many seconds.

I don't see anything else documented or in the code that would leave me to believe there was a difference.

Comment: 86400 default (1hr) seems like a huge value to me for that particular stat - I would have thought 5 mins would have been a better default? Plus, in this case, I can't understand how it can be both Global and Session - either the data is updated for everybody, or it isn't?

Comment: It is updated for everyone, but only when *your* session calls it.

Comment: +1 on both for having taught me something! :-)

Comment: @Vérace The last time I checked, 86400 seconds was 24 hours.  A long time, but reasonable considering the activity to keep queries running consistently from one day to another.

Comment: @WilsonHauck of course I meant 1 day! (Doh... slaps forehead...). But seriously, you're telling me that it's OK to have the reported size of a table and its true size to be out of step by 24 hours? Sorry, but I have to disagree there! And I fail to see what the correct (witihin, say, 5 minutes) reporting of this measurement has to  do with keeping queries running consistently.

Comment: Sorry - I don't get you?

Comment: @Vérace I just deleted my comment. I agree with your sentiment that it's not OK to cache things for a 24 hours. But I don't think anyone expects MySQL to be used where it matters. Why is the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tied to the statistics for the table? Another **GREAT** question? Why does `SELECT table_schema AS db_name, SUM(data_length + index_length) AS size
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
GROUP BY db_name` refresh statistics? There is no good reason. It's just a bottom up design that never had to rise above the low bar.

Comment: `But I don't think anyone expects MySQL to be used where it matters` - tell that to Facebook and all the other massive corps who use it! ;-0

Comment: There is no disputing that Facebook uses it. Most of the advances are probably done by Facebook now. They get a lot of really weird perks too.

Comment: Gotta ask - what are these "wierd perks"?

Comment: There is a GREATFULLY ACKWNOELDGES statement somewhere on the site, the commit messages get to be marked with the wonderfully descriptive "COMMIT FROM FACEBOOK" (or something like that), I think there is a COPYING.FACEBOOK somewhere in there too. The files that they started retain copyright notices (which aren't given to Oracle on commit). Pretty much anything just so they don't fork (which they did previously), or spin off their own competition (like websql)